# Why doesn't this piece of code cast down and change the array value?

Tags: c++

I'm learning about c on c paradigms with stanford. https://youtu.be/H4MQXBF6FN4?t=1762

The professor shows this piece of code and says it will change the bit pattern of the array.

Shorts are 2 Bytes and Ints are 4 bytes.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    arr[3] = 128;     // 0000 0000 1000 0000
    ((short*)arr)[6] = 2;  //  0000 0010

    std::cout << arr[3];  // my compiler prints out 2, should it be 640? should be 512 + 128????   1010000000 would be the bit pattern?


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Retagged. This is C++.

Comment: depends on what processor (bigendian or littel endian)

Comment: intel x86 on windows.

Comment: you will become much wiser in CS if you work the answer out yourself. x86 is little endian. Google and read . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: thank you.  i missed the part of big endian vs little endian. makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Your int is probably 64-bits so second assignment does not hit the target.

The professor assumed 32-bit int.

Try to print sizeof(int) and sizeof(short).

Edit:
As iMoses said this happens because 16 bit value of 2 overwrites 128 on little endian CPU

Comment: This has nothing to do with int size. While the size of int is not explicitly defined in C++ (except for a lower limit which I do not remember right now) - it is usually 32 bits long even on 64 bit platforms. The professor must have used a big endian CPU.

Comment: @runners3431 And sizeof(short)?

Comment: For little endian the value gets overwritten so 2 is correct result